# Descarga de ficheros Python Selenium Chromedriver - Error de Red

Tags: python-3.7, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

me estoy encontrando con problemas al descargar ficheros de una web. Si lo hago de manera manual funciona perfectamente pero si lanzo el script de automatización hecho con Python 3.7 y Selenium con ChromeDriver me da un fallo de "Error de red"

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

prefs = {
            'download.default_directory': 'D:\\Descargas\\COL'
        }

options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\drivers_navegadores\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
```

He intentado añadir también estas opciones con el mismo resultado:

```
        'download.prompt_for_download': False,
        'download.directory_upgrade': True,
        'safebrowsing.enabled': True
```

Solo puedo usar ChromeDriver porque la web no permite el uso de otros navegadores. Toda la navegación hasta llegar a la descarga es correcta pero en el momento de pulsar el botón de descarga, da el error. El tipo de fichero a descargar es un zip, en otras automatizaciones en otras webs también se descargan este tipo de ficheros pero no dan ningún tipo de problema. También he probado a cambiar el directorio de descarga con el mismo resultado ¿Alguna pista de por dónde pueden ir los tiros?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Puedes añadir la traza de error completa por favor, eso nos hará más fácil el poder resolverte el problema. Nunca hay que escatimar en información :)

Comment: Hola Alberto, misteriosamente cuando he probado para sacar las trazas que me solicitabas, ha funcionado a la primera, sin tocar nada respecto al script que tenía. De hecho he probado dos veces porque tenía la intuición de que el problema podía venir de que cuando descargaba un fichero ya descargado previamente, era cuando se producía el error. Pero no, ha funcionado correctamente. Misterios... Gracias por el interés

Comment: Jaja, perfecto entonces, es que cuando vi el código, me pareció que lo tenías todo correcto. Me alegro de que todo vaya bien!